# Sum numbers in a list of lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, list, sum

I've got a list of lists in Python 2.7 with numbers in strings:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

How could I sum all the numbers in these lists?

Comment: One way would be to flatten the list, parse the elements and calculate the sum. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are lots of ways. What have you tried?

Comment: `sum([int(i) for s in a for i in s])` where `a` is your list

Comment: @tom Why the list comprehension?

Comment: @tom Why not `int()`?

Comment: @PeterWood its an alternative that works? unless you have a particular reason why not? KevenGuan - fair enough

Comment: @tom Why not `sum(int(i) for s in a for i in s)`?

Comment: @PeterWood yeah ok, you win.

Answer (score 3):

You have first `chain` all the lists, then convert them to `int` using `map` and finally `sum` them.

```
import itertools
m =  [['1', '2'], ['3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
print sum(map(int, list(itertools.chain(*m))))
```

Output:

```
21
```

Comment: You don't *have* to chain them.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate solution to chaining them you could use list comprehension and convert each element to an int and then sum the new list

```
l = [['1', '2'], ['3'], ['4', '5', '6']]

print sum([int(j) for i in l for j in i])

21
```